# How to optimize Media Composer performance on a MacBook Pro (2021)?

Tags: avid, media, macbook

My wife is trying to use Media Composer 2022.10.0 on her rather new MacBook Pro (2021) and compared to her iMac (2019) it seems not to work as smoothly as she expected. Sadly I never worked with MC and/or Premiere myself. Is there a way to optimize its performance on the laptop?

MacBook Pro (14", 2021, M1 Pro, 32 Gb RAM, macOS 12.4), MC 2022.10.0

iMac (21.5", 2019, i7, 16 Gb RAM, Radeon Pro 560 X 4 Gb, macOS 10.15.7), MC 2020.8.0

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update to macOS Ventura (13.0) solved the problem!